# MALLET tokenizer

Tags: nlp, tokenize

Hi I want to use MALLET's topic modeling but can i provide my own tokenizer or tokenized version of the text documents when i import the data into mallet? I find MALLET's tokenizer inadequate for my usage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Simply replace the default tokenizer with my own into the serial pipe and add it into the instance list.